# Can't get User Location Using MKMapViewDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, mkmapview

I have been reading tutorials about getting user location for several hours, yet I cannot seem to get it. I have my `ViewController` class implementing `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and `MKMapViewDelegate`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.mapView.delegate = self
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    print("Is User Location Visible: \(self.mapView.userLocation.location?.coordinate.latitude)")
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        print("Authorization Status = \(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .Denied || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined)")
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    else{
        print("location services disabled")
    }
}
```

This seems like it would work, as I have set `showsUserLocation` to `true` with `MKMapView` and started updating location services with `CLLocationManager`.

However, the printout of `viewDidLoad()` is:

```
Is User Location Visible: nil
Authorization Status = false
```

Whenever I try to access user location, it's nil.

I have `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` set in Info.plist as well, it successfully asked me if I want to allow location services and I clicked yes.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here is the full code of `MapViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var mapView: MKMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func loadView() {


    // create a map view
    mapView = MKMapView()

    // set the map view we just created as the view for this controller
    view = mapView

    let ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Standard", "Hybrid", "Satellite", "My Location"])
    ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
    ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

    ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MapViewController.mapTypeChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​segmentedControl)

    let topConstraint = ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8)


    let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
    let leadingConstraint = ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​segmentedControl.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.leadingAnchor)
    let trailingConstraint = ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​segmentedControl.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.trailingAnchor)

    topConstraint.active = true
    leadingConstraint.active = true
    trailingConstraint.active = true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    print("Is User Location Visible: \(mapView.userLocation.location?.coordinate.latitude)")
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        print("Authorization Status = \(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse)")
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    else{
        print("location services disabled")
    }
}

func mapTypeChanged(segControl: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch segControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        mapView.mapType = .Standard
    case 1:
        mapView.mapType = .Hybrid
    case 2:
        mapView.mapType = .Satellite
    case 3:
        zoomOnLocation()
    default:
        break
    }
}

//Zoom to last known location
func zoomOnLocation() {
    print("locations = \(self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude) ")
    var location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.5, 0.5))
    print("zooming")
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}

//Delegate if Location has Changed
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
}

//Delegate if Authorization Status has Changed
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus){
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}


func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation!){
    let coord = userLocation.coordinate
    print("delegate: coord = \(coord.longitude)")
}

func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(mapView: MKMapView!){
    print("finished loading mapview")
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

    print("Is User Location Visible: \(self.mapView.userLocationVisible)")

}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, mapViewWillStartLocatingUser userLocation: MKUserLocation!){
    let coord = userLocation.coordinate
    print("delegate: coord = \(coord.longitude)")
}

}
```

Comment: Log the actual authorization status, not a BOOL comparing it to 2 values. And you need to make the call that asks the user for authorization. (Don't have it in front of me.)

Comment: print("Authorization Status = \(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse)")     returns true

Comment: Is your location manager didUpdateLocation method being called?

Comment: no. Also, CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() is evaluating to true

Comment: Did the popup asking for authorization pop and did you add the key in the `Info.plist` file corresponding to `AuthorizedWhenInUse` ?

Comment: Yes. I have been told this could be due to me running the code on the Simulator.